# Place 3d model in SCNNode without tapping

Tags: swift, augmented-reality

I'm new to ARKit.
I have a horizontal plane detected and scnnode created from it. When I tap on it, I display a 3d model in the place where I tapped. 
Question is, is there a way to "simulate" that tap? And to place the 3d model anywhere in that plane (for instance, the center) without even tapping?.

I supposed I need to fake an ARHitTestResult, but I'm a little bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a couple of hours researching, I found the solution.
I used the function `plane = self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "you_plane_name_here", recursively: true)` to obtain the plane.
Then, to get the center of that plane, I used `plane.worldPosition`.
And then, after I've created the new node for my 3d model, I just did:

```
node.position = plane.worldPosition
plane.addChildNode(node)
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

And that was it! The 3d model appear at the center of the plane.

Hope it helps someone!